# Need help to generate map file for mapserver using GML as input

Tags: gis, qgis, mapserver

Hello I need help to generate map file for GML file
here is  my map file

```
MAP
  IMAGETYPE      PNG
  EXTENT 359306.4  534654.0  362290.7 536664.3
  SIZE           800 800
  IMAGECOLOR     255 255 255
  CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/var/log/map/ms_error.txt"
  DEBUG 5
  MAXSIZE 4096

LAYER
    NAME "line"
    TYPE LINE
    STATUS ON
    CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
    CONNECTION "/var/www/maps/NY63NW.gml"
    DUMP TRUE
    MINSCALE 0
    MAXSCALE 1000000
    SYMBOLSCALE 1000

    EXTENT 359306.4  534654.0  362290.7 536664.3
        METADATA
            gml_include_items   "all"
            wms_include_items   "all"
        END
    CLASS
            STYLE
                COLOR 255 136 0
            END
    END
    PROJECTION
       "init=epsg:27700"
    END
END
```

but image is blank when I load

http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/maps/polt.map&mode=map

Im new to mapserver and any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

With out access to the actual file or the error message in the log file it is almost impossible to answer this question. However, best practice is not to serve data directly from a GML file but to use `ogr2ogr` to convert it into a more efficient format. Ideally, this would be a database like PostGIS but if you need to keep with file formats something like GeoPackage will be much more efficient than GML.